# Create table-returning function in package, using %ROWTYPE and TABLE OF

Tags: oracle, oracle11gr2

I have some tables which I cannot change. For each table, I need to create a `FUNCTION` inside a `PACKAGE` that returns a temporary table with the same data/layout as the original table. Instead of copying all table column definitions manually, I'd like to use statements such as `%ROWTYPE`.

**I want to tell Oracle: "this function returns a table with the same layout as the original table XY".**

Please have a look at this example. This is the (legacy) table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST.Emp (
    ID RAW(16),
    NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
/
```

These are the package and type definitions:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST.row_Emp AS OBJECT (
    ID RAW(16),
    NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE TEST.Emp_PKG AS
    TYPE t_Emp IS TABLE OF TEST.row_Emp INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

    FUNCTION F_Emp_Select (
        VersionId INT DEFAULT NULL
    ) RETURN t_Emp;

END;
/
```

And here is the package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TEST.Emp_PKG AS

    FUNCTION F_Emp_Select (
        VersionId INT DEFAULT NULL
    ) RETURN t_Emp
    AS
        VersionVar INT := VersionId;
        v_ret t_Emp;
    BEGIN

        SELECT
            CAST(
                MULTISET(
                    SELECT ID, NAME FROM TEST.Emp
                ) AS t_Emp)                         -- <== this is line 15
            INTO v_ret
            FROM dual;

        RETURN v_ret;
    END;
END;
/
```

If I execute this in SQLPlus, I get the following error:

```
Errors for PACKAGE BODY TEST.EMP_PKG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/9     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
15/22    PL/SQL: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**EDIT:** I need this for a more complex case. This function will be used in other functions and procedures. For example, I need to be able to do a join on the result of the function:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
INNER JOIN TEST.Emp_PKG.F_Emp_Select(...) ON ...
```

So I don't need the whole result.

Sorry for the confusion, I'm coming from SQL Server, where I have done such things many times.

Comment: What's your end goal here - are you just creating a CRUD wrapper around the table - in which case would a function returning a refcursor suffice? - or do you actually want a collection? Do you need the whole thing or could you pipeline it to reduce memory usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the result as something you can treat as a table, you could use a pipeline function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE row_Emp AS OBJECT (
    ID RAW(16),
    NAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_Emp AS TABLE OF row_Emp
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Emp_PKG AS

    FUNCTION F_Emp_Select (
        VersionId INT DEFAULT NULL
    ) RETURN tab_Emp PIPELINED;

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Emp_PKG AS

    FUNCTION F_Emp_Select (
        VersionId INT DEFAULT NULL
    ) RETURN tab_EMP PIPELINED
    AS
    BEGIN

        FOR row IN (SELECT ID, NAME FROM Emp) LOOP
          PIPE ROW (row_Emp(row.ID, row.NAME));
        END LOOP;

        RETURN;
    END;
END;
/
```

Notice the object type and the table type have to be declared at schema level; the table type can't be a PL/SQL-seclared table (collection) type as that wouldn't be usable in plain SQL, even within other PL/SQL. Unfortunately `%ROWTYPE` is a PL/SQL construct, so you can't use that to define your schema-level table type.

You can then do:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(Emp_PKG.F_Emp_Select(<optional versionId>));
```

... or use it in a join as:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
INNER JOIN TABLE(TEST.Emp_PKG.F_Emp_Select(...)) ON ...
```

[SQL FIddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1e171/1).

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems like exactly what I need. Gonna try it tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your goal is to return a collection, not a temporary table, it's a bit less complicated than your example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE emp_pkg
AS
  TYPE emp_typ IS TABLE OF emp%rowtype index by binary_integer;

  FUNCTION get_emps
    RETURN emp_typ;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_pkg
AS
  FUNCTION get_emps
    RETURN emp_typ
  IS
    l_emps emp_typ;
  BEGIN
    SELECT *
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_emps
      FROM emp;

    RETURN l_emps;
  END;
END;
```

Now, architecturally, I would be **very** concerned about a solution that involved selecting all the data from a table into a PL/SQL collection.  PL/SQL collections have to be stored entirely in the session's SGA which is relatively expensive server RAM.  If you have thousands or tens of thousands of rows in your table, that can be a pretty substantial amount of space on the server particularly if there may be many different sessions all calling these procedures at roughly the same time.  If your tables all have a couple hundred rows and only one session at a time will be using these functions, maybe this approach will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I don't need the result as a collection, please see my edit.